# Invalid Token, error while sending push notification

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to send push notitfication to ios using worklight. But while sending it, IDE shows invalid token id error in logs.

I am trying this by signing my app using sandbox certificate.

Please help.

I am successfully send notification to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add the actual full error from the Xcode console and Worklight Server?

Meanwhile, make sure everything is set-up correctly. The Developer Certificate, the PNS certificate, the App ID, provisioning profile, ... You can [follow this guide](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding-and-setting-up-push-notifications-in-development-evnironment?lang=en).

Also consult [with the Push Notifications training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/09_04_Push_notifications.pdf) (slide #44) and make sure all required ports are open and that you are able to ping the APNS servers.

Comment: hi i am implimenting and follow all steps but got same error
any suggestion bro you and my backend deleloper got a error 
`invalidregistration`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460024/invalid-registration-while-sending-push-notification-in-php