# Invalid registration while sending push notification in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am following this [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) Server Side Implementation.](http://sab99r.com/blog/firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-php-backend/) . but got an error of `invalidregistrationid`.

Did googling but found nothing.
I also found some related problem which already answered on StackOverflow. but got no solutions.
the following link I visited for the solution.

1. [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349029/invalid-token-error-while-sending-push-notification).
2. [B link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618633/invalid-registration-id-fcm).

```
class abc{
  function send_android_notification($registration_ids="2fa86bbc8bc4aee204255a0d84461c000a26442312d0a9b1df1664d461fd3b7d") {
      $message = array('title' => 'CodeCastra', 'body' => "hi huye" ,'sound'=>'Default','image'=>'Notification Image' );
      define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "AIzaSyDDvpPcWfOTVkkvA-yQg4yTYzIuh0MNIRw"); //legacy server key
      $fields = array(
          'registration_ids' => (array)$registration_ids,
          'notification' => $message, //note: body & title fileds must be specified for the message or your only get just the vibration but the notification
      );
      $headers = array(
          'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY, //  FIREBASE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID_NOTIFICATION
          'Content-Type: application/json'
      );
      //Open connection
      $ch = curl_init();
      //Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
      //echo json_encode($fields);
      //print_r($headers);
      //exit;
      //Execute post
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      if ($result === false) {
          die('Curl failed:' . curl_errno($ch));
      }
      // Close connection
      curl_close($ch);
      return $result;
  }

}

print_r((new abc)->send_android_notification());
die;
```

```
{"multicast_id":4707836736661373968,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614607/invalidregistration-error-in-firebase-cloud-messaging-for-android

Comment: hi @Dharman i am not using pem file i am using firebase access token for push notifications

Comment: I am not an expert on Firebase, but either way I know you should not disable these two options. Read the linked article in full, maybe it will help you set cUrl on firebase properly too.

Comment: @Dharman thanks for your suggession but my error is solved

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am implementing your code.

Use `firebase registration token` it generated in device (ios/android)
instead of the Device token .
`'registration_ids' => (array)$token,`

Hope it's helpful